# How to query data from a database into different div codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have problem with my project. I want to loop my data into different div.

Example:

```
table1:
id  image  description
1   1.png  aa
2   2.png  bb
3   3.png  cc
4   4.png  dd
5   5.png  ee
6   6.png  ff
7   7.png  gg
```

I have two div left div and right div and I want the result:

```
1.png  aa
         2.png  bb
3.png  cc
         4.png  dd
5.png  ee
         6.png  ff
7.png  gg
```

This is my code in view:

```
<?php 
$query = $this->db->get('table1');
foreach($query->result() as $val):
?>
<div id="left">
<img src="<?php echo base_url().'./images/'.$val->image ?>">
<p><?php echo $val->description; ?></p>
</div>
<div id="right">
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and the result like that:

```
1.png  aa
2.png  bb
3.png  cc
4.png  dd
5.png  ee
6.png  ff
7.png  gg
```

Comment: Do you already have some working code to show us? If you already have the two left and right divs what are you asking. This is potentially sounding like a CSS answer instead of your tags for php, jquery, and codeigniter. The more you can give us the better we can help :)

Comment: I can do only simple query with codeigniter from database .but query into deferent div I can not do .could you help me Dijkgraaf :(

Comment: you want result like how you have posted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve the above easily with `TABLE`, but if you want to do it with `div`,
try this.

```
<div class="float_left">
    <div class="float_left">1.png aa</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="float_right">2.png bb</div>
    <div class="float_left">3.png cc</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="float_right">4.png dd</div>
</div>
```

css for the code.

```
float_left{    
    float: left;
    margin-right: 100px;
    clear: both;
}
.float_right{    
    float: right;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

For demo, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7kL8asq5/2/)

```
<div class="float_left">
        <?php
        $var = "left";
        foreach ($variable as $a) {
            echo "<div class='float_$var'>$a->image" . " " . "$a->description </div>";
            $var = $var == "left" ? "right" : "left";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: for css html I can do .but when I query from database I can not

Comment: use foreach loop for this.

Comment: did u hav and email ?

Comment: How to loop like this

Comment: Hi Nirabjan N Raju  I folowwing ur code but it is double result :(

Comment: check the answer now.

Comment: Did u have team viewer ?

Comment: Hi Niranjan N Raju its work for me  .I am  very very thz q :D you are the best web developer :D and kindly

Comment: @user307709 you got desired output??

Comment: did u have an email ?

Comment: I am very thz q again   :D and nice to know you :D

Comment: see this, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: check the first answer.

Comment: @user307709 its ok, Thank you:)